# VxWorks passing struct address into ioctl

Tags: c, driver, ioctl, vxworks

I'm trying to pass the address of a structure as the 3rd parameter of *ioctl()*. I am unable to access the structure members when I try to read them inside *my_ioctl()*. I read the address before I pass it to *ioctl()*, then I cast the address inside *my_ioctl()* to the structure pointer type and assign it to a new pointer variable. Then, when I read the address again, it doesn't match the address I originally passed into it.

so

```
MY_STRUCT struct;

MY_STRUCT *pStruct = &struct;  

printf("address before ioctl: x%08X\n", (int)pStruct);

if(ioctl(fd, command, (int)pStruct) < 0)
```

.
.
.

then in the driver

```
int my_ioctl(struct dev *pDev, int cmd, int arg)

MY_STRUCT *pStruct = (MY_STRUCT*)arg;

printf("addr in ioctl: x08X\n", pStruct);
   
   switch(cmd)
```

.
.
.

Why is the address changing?

Comment: You need to do `copy_from_user`

Comment: @stark I've seen that done in linux drivers but does vxworks have a copy_from_user function as well?

Comment: In the second printf(), % is missing in the format. Is it a typo ?

Answer (score 0):

Casting a pointer into an integer is a bad practice. For example, on x86_64, a pointer is 8 bytes long and an integer is 4 bytes long...

According to [this document](https://docs.windriver.com/bundle/vxworks_7_application_core_os_sr0630-enus/page/CORE/ioLib.html#ioctl), the 3rd argument of *ioctl()* has a type which fits the target architecture:

> The third argument is optional, _Vx_ioctl_arg_t type is recommended, then for VxWorks 32-bits, this is a 32-bits type, and for VxWorks 64-bits, this is a 64-bits type.

Comment: That is true. I just looked in ioLib.h and for my system _Vx_ioctl_arg_t is define as int. I changed the cast to (_Vx_ioctl_arg_t) just to be proper but still same results.

Comment: What is the architecture : 64 bits or 32 bits ?

Comment: Please edit your answer with what you did because replacing "if (ioctl(fd, command, (int)pStruct) < 0)" by "if (ioctl(fd, command, (_Vx_ioctl_arg_t)pStruct) < 0)" is not sufficient. The entry point of your driver must define its parameter the same way : int my_ioctl(struct dev *pDev, int cmd,  _Vx_ioctl_arg_t arg).

Comment: It's 32 bit which is why I said _Vx_ioctl_arg_t was the same as int. _Vx_ioctl_arg_t is defined as int so it  doesn't matter. It changes nothing about the behavior. The compiler will replace _Vx_ioctl_arg_t with int anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem a few months ago. The Problem here is most likely that some of the IOCTL cmds are blocked/already used by vxWorks (tested on Version 7 SR620).

Check if you get cmd code 64. If you get a 64 as cmd your addr your getting is most likeli garbage.

A coworker checked for ioctl cmds that go through and found that cmds 2,3,7,14,15,19,20,21,.. should go through, but no guarantees that these command codes work for you.

Comment: Yeah I spoke with a vxworks support tech and that's what it ended up being. It just so happened that the cmd I was passing when I saw this issue was to allocate a block of memory and pass that address instead of the struct address. It made it appear that my struct was being corrupted but, actually it was completely different memory block. I had to add an offset to all my cmds to push them all past the vxworks predefined cmds.